# I did bad stuff i dont want to be punished by allah

Tags: allah

I am Muslim but shaitan took me away and I looked at girls' private parts, what can I do so Allah can forgive me?

Answer (score 0):

Confessing a sin to others is not allowed in Islam.

> Abu Hurayrah said: I heard the Messenger of Allah (peace and blessings of Allah be upon >him) say: “All of my ummah will be forgiven except those who sin openly. It is a part of >sinning openly when a man does something at night, then the following morning when Allah >has concealed his sin, he says, ‘O So and so, I did such and such last night,’ when all >night his Lord has concealed him and the next morning he uncovers what Allah had >concealed.”
> (Narrated by al-Bukhaari, 5721; Muslim, 2990).

Make Tauba and seek forgiveness from Allah. Consult your local Imaam or Masjid.